# Send an email from Excel 2007 VBA using an Outlook Template & Set Variables

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a list of data, let's say client information (Name, Email, Amount Owing etc.), stored in an Excel worksheet. My aim is to click a button in Excel and send each client their information in an Outlook Template.

1. create a mail object
2. set the mail object to the template file
3. setting and then filling in the template with data about the current client - mostly stuck here, not sure how to specify variables in a template and then relate to them in VBA
4. save to drafts for later review/send

e.g. Dear << clientname >> = Dear John Smith

My code thus far:

```
Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application
Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = myOlApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\egTemplate.oft")

With MyItem
    .To = Worksheets("Clients").Range(1, 2)
    .Subject = "Monthly bill"
    'Refer to and fill in variable items in template
    .Save
End With

Set MyItem = Nothing
Set MyOlApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what you can do :

```
With MyItem
    'Refer to and fill in variable items in template
    .Body = Replace(.Body, "<< clientname >>", Worksheets("Clients").Range(1, 2))
End With
```

or, if your mail is in HTML:

```
With MyItem
    'Refer to and fill in variable items in template
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "&lt;&lt; clientname &gt;&gt;",  Worksheets("Clients").Range(1, 2))
End With
```

Tested successfully on Excel / Outlook 2007

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect job for mail merge. If you want to do it programmatically, see

[Mail Merge in Word+Excel using VBA](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba-mail-merge-in-excel/)

Or you could simply do it manually (from Word), inserting merge fields and then selecting your workbook as the data source. You can merge to email and Outlook will send out personalized emails to each recipient's email using the information from each row/record.

Comment: Thanks mate, this solution had already been built though and was looking for a quick change. I know how effective Mail Merge is though and appreciate the answer.

Comment: I'd actually disagree. Word mail merge has some MAJOR issues, such as: Subject is fixed text - can only overcome via Outlook VB macro or other programattical option Can only send to one email recipitent. If you want to send an email TO and CC, you can't. You can't even combine the two emails into the To email address. Brian