# Body.Replace strips out html formatting

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an email template which has html formatting and place holders to swap out with real values.

In Excel I load the email via the Outlook CreateItemFromTemplate method. If at this point I save the email formatting is preserved.

If I perform a replace on the body most of the formatting is stripped out:

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("template.oft") ' <- has lots of html formatting

With OutMail
    .Body = Replace(.Body, "#recipient#", "Some other value") ' <- Strips out most formatting!!
    .Save ' <- this works fine without the line above.
End With
```

Comment: Replace `.Body` with `.HTMLBody`

Comment: Thanks Scott - I just got that.

Comment: Scott if you add this as an answer I will mark it as such

Comment: Thanks hugh. Appreciate the thought! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8473313/569662

My problem was you have to use `.HTMLBody` rather than `.Body` :

```
.HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, "#recipient#", "Some other value")
```